# Invalid Resx file. No valid icon entry were found

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, travis-ci, resx

I'm trying to setup this project on a CI platform, and whenever it tries to build, it returns this one error: `Invalid Resx file. No valid icon entry were found.` The icon is there but there's no reference to the actual file location in the .resx for the form (where the error is coming from). It's on line 270 apparently.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <!-- 
    Microsoft ResX Schema 

    Version 2.0

    The primary goals of this format is to allow a simple XML format 
    that is mostly human readable. The generation and parsing of the 
    various data types are done through the TypeConverter classes 
    associated with the data types.

    Example:

    ... ado.net/XML headers & schema ...
    <resheader name="resmimetype">text/microsoft-resx</resheader>
    <resheader name="version">2.0</resheader>
    <resheader name="reader">System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, ...</resheader>
    <resheader name="writer">System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, ...</resheader>
    <data name="Name1"><value>this is my long string</value><comment>this is a comment</comment></data>
    <data name="Color1" type="System.Drawing.Color, System.Drawing">Blue</data>
    <data name="Bitmap1" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">
        <value>[base64 mime encoded serialized .NET Framework object]</value>
    </data>
    <data name="Icon1" type="System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
        <value>[base64 mime encoded string representing a byte array form of the .NET Framework object]</value>
        <comment>This is a comment</comment>
    </data>

    There are any number of "resheader" rows that contain simple 
    name/value pairs.

    Each data row contains a name, and value. The row also contains a 
    type or mimetype. Type corresponds to a .NET class that support 
    text/value conversion through the TypeConverter architecture. 
    Classes that don't support this are serialized and stored with the 
    mimetype set.

    The mimetype is used for serialized objects, and tells the 
    ResXResourceReader how to depersist the object. This is currently not 
    extensible. For a given mimetype the value must be set accordingly:

    Note - application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64 is the format 
    that the ResXResourceWriter will generate, however the reader can 
    read any of the formats listed below.

    mimetype: application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64
    value   : The object must be serialized with 
            : System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
            : and then encoded with base64 encoding.

    mimetype: application/x-microsoft.net.object.soap.base64
    value   : The object must be serialized with 
            : System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter
            : and then encoded with base64 encoding.

    mimetype: application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64
    value   : The object must be serialized into a byte array 
            : using a System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter
            : and then encoded with base64 encoding.
    -->
  <xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" />
    <xsd:element name="root" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:element name="metadata">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="assembly">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:attribute name="alias" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="data">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                <xsd:element name="comment" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="3" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="4" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="resheader">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
  <resheader name="resmimetype">
    <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="version">
    <value>2.0</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="reader">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="writer">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <assembly alias="System.Drawing" name="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  <data name="$this.Icon" type="System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
    <value>
        AAABAAEAAAAAAAEACADqIQAAFgAAAIlQTkcNChoKAAAADUlIRFIAAAH0AAAB9AgGAAAAy9bfigAAIABJ
        REFUeJzt3XmUZnV95/HPsy/VtfS+0zvdjSLN1tgNHKOgMZoMTMiYMxNRGHPIOUk8QnQGxtFJJkfE5Ixi
        EufMDCMBiZG4MCZi1EQExe6G3th6X6uX6n2p/dmf+8wfLdDQVd21PM/zu/d7369zONSpLur5AlX1rnt/
        9/5uZOfsu2oCAACBFnU9AAAAGD+CDgCAAQQdAAADCDoAAAYQdAAADCDoAAAYQNABADCAoAMAYABBBwDA
        AIIOAIABBB0AAAMIOgAABhB0AAAMIOgAABhA0AEAMICgAwBgAEEHAMAAgg4AgAEEHQAAAwg6AAAGEHQA
        AAwg6AAAGEDQAQAwgKADAGAAQQcAwACCDgCAAQQdAAADCDoAAAYQdAAADCDoAAAYQNABADCAoAMAYABB
        BwDAAIIOAIABBB0AAAMIOgAABhB0AAAMIOgAABhA0AEAMICgAwBgAEEHAMAAgg4AgAEEHQAAAwg6AAAG
        EHQAAAwg6AAAGEDQAQAwgKADAGAAQQcAwACCDgCAAQQdAAADCDoAAAYQdAAADCDoAAAYQNABADCAoAMA
        YABBBwDAAIIOAIABBB0AAAMIOgAABhB0AAAMIOgAABhA0AEAMICgAwBgAEEHAMAAgg4AgAEEHQAAAwg6
        AAAGEHQAAAwg6AAAGEDQAQAwgKADAGAAQQcAwACCDgCAAQQdAAADCDoAAAYQdAAADCDoAAAYQNABADCA
        oAMAYABBBwDAAIIOAIABBB0AAAMIOgAABhB0AAAMIOgAABhA0AEAMICgAwBgAEEHAMAAgg4AgAEEHQAA
        Awg6AAAGEHQAAAwg6AAAGEDQAQAwgKADAGAAQQcAwACCDgCAAQQdAAADCDoAAAYQdAAADCDoAAAYQNAB
        ADCAoAMAYABBBwDAAIIOAIABBB0AAAMIOgAABhB0AAAMIOgAABhA0AEAMICgAwBgAEEHAMAAgg4AgAEE
        HQAAAwg6AAAGEHQAAAwg6AAAGEDQAQAwgKADAGAAQQcAwACCDgCAAQQdAAADCDoAAAYQdAAADCDoAAAY
        QNABADCAoAMAYABBBwDAAIIOAIABBB0AAAMIOgAABhB0AAAMIOgAABhA0AEAMICgAwBgAEEHAMAAgg4A
        gAEEHQAAAwg6AAAGEHQAAAwg6AAAGEDQAQAwgKADAGAAQQcAwACCDgCAAQQdAAADCDoAAAYQdAAADCDo
        AAAYQNABADCAoAMAYABBBwDAAIIOAIABBB0AAAMIOgAABhB0AAAMIOgAABhA0AEAMICgAwBgAEEHAMAA
        gg4AgAEEHQAAAwg6AAAGEHQAAAwg6AAAGEDQAQAwgKADAGAAQQcAwACCDgCAAQQdAAADCDoAAAYQdAAA
        DCDoAAAYQNABADCAoAMAYABBBwDAAIIOAIABBB0AAAMIOgAABhB0AAAMIOgAABgQdz3AaC3tesz1CM55
        1apq5apUrqhWrqpWOfeXylXVShVV+3PyevPy+nKq9uXO/b13UNXuQVWOnlX56BlVjnWrNlBw/a/iK3xt
        Xajrnq9p8EebXY8xZumVSzTv/33W9Ri+smvO3U5eN6jfX67+e41F4IIOKRqLSbGYlE6O6/NU+3MqHz2r
        ytFulfYdU3HXERV3dam0+yixhySpZdWyQAc9c8PlrkcAmoagh1isNavY0qy0dI703ivf8melo2dU2tml
        /OZ9ym/YrfzL+6VC2dGkcCWzepnrEcYlu3Kp6xGApiHoGFJy1mQlZ03WhPddJUnySmUVthxUfv1uDf5y
        m3LrdipS9RxPiUZLL52j6KQJ8s4OuB5l1GqRiNLXLnI9BtA0BB0jEk0mlL12sbLXLtbkP/yQKr2DGnzm
        VfX/ZLMGn9vC0bth2dXLNPDDTa7HGLXU8jmKt2VdjwE0DUHHmMTbW9R+x2q137Fa1VxRgz99Rd3f+JkK
        G/a4Hg11ll29PJBBZ/0cYUPQMW6xbEptt92gtttuUGHHYfU88ax6v7dOypdcj4Y6yK4K5jp6lqAjZLgP
        HXWVXj5XMx76uBZtflgTP/mbUjrheiSMU2rJLEWntLkeY9Qy1xN0hAtBR0PE27Kadv8dWrjuL9V+53tV
        i/GlFmTZgF3tHp83VYnpHa7HAJqKn7JoqMS0Ds146GNa8NyDSl+/xPU4GKOgBT27kqNzhA9BR1OkFs7Q
        3O/dryn/5XekOF92QZNdvdz1CKPCBXEII36yommisZgm/9GHNe9Hf6bEkpmux8EopBbOUGx6u+sxRizD
        ETpCiKCj6dJXzNVl//S5wO9CFjbZVcE4So9OblVq4QzXYwBNR9DhRLwtqzl/9ydqve0G16NghIKyjs7p
        doQVQYcz0VRCM/7mHrXfdYvrUTACQTmjwv3nCCuCDqei0aim/fd/r5YPXuN6FFxCav50xWZOdD3GJbF+
        jrAi6HAuGotp5l/fo9RV812Pgkvw+2n3SDal1PK5rscAnCDo8IVYNqXZj9+r2LTgXEkdRn6/fS1z3WJF
        4zHXYwBOEHT4RmJqu6Y/eKfrMXARft/XnQviEGYEHb7S+hvXquVD17oeA8NIXjZV8dmTXY8xrAy7ESLE
        CDp8Z/oXPqpIW8b1GBiGb692j0eVvnqR6ykAZwg6fCcxrUMTP/F+12NgGH69MC71rgWKZZKuxwCcIejw
        pYl33SKl4q7HwBD8uo7O/ecIO4IOX4pPblP7797segwMITlniuJzp7ge4wKZlayfI9wIOnxr4u9/wPUI
        GIbfTrvXJGWuI+gIN4IO30otnKHk0tmux8AQ/HY/emrpbMUnTnA9BuAUQYevtXxghesRMISMz9bR2e4V
        IOjwuQnvv9r1CBhCctYkxedPcz3GG1g/Bwg6fC69YgH3pPuUn9bR2SEOIOjwuWg0qtSyOa7HwBD8cvta
        fPZkJWf5d/c6oFkIOnwvxYVxvuSXoHN0DpzDzh1NsmvO3Zf8mFosqkgipmg6oWhbVrH2FsWnd5w7Apk/
        Tallc5S6Yq7ik9uaMLF/pJZyhO5HiRkTlVg4Q+X9x53Owfo5cA5B95FI1ZOqnrxCWV5PThWdVnHLwbd8
        TE1S8vJZarnpCrV++Dqlr1usaMz24yKTi2e6HgHDyK5epl7nQecIHZA45R44EUnl3UfV87fP6PAdX1Ln
        jffr7CM/UTVXcD1aw0Q7WlyPgGG4vjAu2tHCL3zArxD0gKt0ndGpP/+2Om96QL3ff8H1OA0RnZB2PQKG
        4fp+9Mz1SxSN8mMMkAi6GdWTvTr+yUd09FOPyCuWXY9TV7FWblvzq8TUdiUcHiFzQRzwJoJuTP9TL6jr
        rq+ainqkhSP003/9tPbddL/rMYbk8rS7q/Xz/h9v1q45d6uaKzp5fWAoBN2g/C+368Tnvul6DNRRNJNU
        +eBJXwbEWdDTCaWvnOfkpQtbD6oWkWLZlJPXB4ZC0I3qe/J5DTy3xfUYdeH15VyP4Fwkk1SkJpV2HXE9
        ygWyq5ap5uB1M9csUjTh5kad4rZDimaIOfyFoBt26ovfcT1CXRB0vRGP4s4ux5NcKD65zcnmPy7Xzwvb
        DinC0Tl8hqAbVtrRpdymPa7HGLcqQVckk5QkFXccdjzJ0Fxc7Z51tH5eOduv6rFuRbNJJ68PDIegGzfw
        ry+7HmHcygdPuR7BueivjgaL2/0Z9Gavo9eiEaWvWdTU13xdYeu5zZ6iXKwJnyHoxhVe3u96hHErvG23
        vDB6I+g7fRr0dy9t6jp6+p3zFHMU1Nd3b4ywhg6fIejGlRxvy1kPxW0E/fVT7l5PTqWjZx1Pc6H4pFal
        ljdvz32n6+dbD0l685cswC8IunHV3mCvP3vVKkfoems8Sn49Sm/iaXdX6+eSVNh6QBI7GMJ/CLpxtVLF
        9Qjjkt+4V7W+vOsxnHv9CF3y8zr68qa9lqsnrFX6cip3npQkRVs4Qoe/EHTjgn7hTv8P1rsewRei6TeD
        Xtjmz6BnVl6uWqTxr5NYOMPZI4SLWw/q9X/FaDbY31uwh6Abl5g9yfUIY+ZVq+r/502ux/CF8y/AKm4/
        5HCS4cUnTlDqissa/jou18/Pf5wxR+jwG4JuXGrZXNcjjNngc1vknel3PYYvxDLJN45+S/tP+HILWKk5
        6+hZlxfEvXbgjbeDfvYL9hB047I3NW9ds97OfPUHrkfwlUgqce7vtZpKu/23BazUnKBnrnezfi5J+dc6
        33ibI3T4DUG3LBXXhA9e63qKMRl4bouKr3Re+gND5Pwr3Yt+XUe/YalqkcYtpMemtys5b1rDPv/FVHoH
        37ggTuI+dPgPQTes/SM3K97R4nqMUfM8T6e/8o+ux/Cd8x8GUvDrOnpbtqFPQMusXNqwz30pxS1vXhAn
        SZF0wtkswFAIulGRtowm3/dvXI8xJr1PPKeigR3u6u38W9f8fG9+I/d1d7p+/spbvyajGfZyh78QdKNm
        PPRxJaZ1uB5j1IoHTujkF77tegxfOv/WteL2Q/KqVYfTDK/lxsYF3dX955KUf9svmZE0QYe/EHSDJt93
        m9puu8H1GKPmVas6ft+jUqHsehRfOv8IXYWyygdODv/BDmWuX6JatP7r6JHWjJIOHtP6urc/FyFK0OEz
        BN2YyZ/5t5ry6dtdjzEmJ//sSRU2Bv9xr43y9jVbv552j7VmlX7X/Lp/3sz1ixWNxer+eUei1HVa1ZO9
        b3kfa+jwG4JuRKQto1n/94815d5grpuf+V8/Vu9jP3M9hq+9fc3Wr0GXGnP7WvYGdxfEFTbvu+B9r99G
        CPgFQQ+4WkRqvWOVFvz8i2r9jWDeotb7/Rd06sHvuB7D96Jvu02quOWAm0FGILuq/vsfuLz/PLfpwjNH
        kWTcwSTA8PiKDKhoR1att6/SxLtvUWrRTNfjjFnPt36h4w98Q03YAjzwLjjl/toBeZ6naNR/v5dnVi5R
        LRZVpOrV5xMm40pftaA+n2sMChv3XvC+SIIfn/AXviJ9rCYpkoor2pJWfHqHEgumK/2Oy5RdtUzpaxYp
        Gneznlgvp778fZ19+AfEfITeflV1baCg8v7jSi2e5Wii4cVa0kpftUDFly48VT0W6RULFHV0irvan1Nh
        26ELvk4jiWB//8Eegt4kS7secz2Cb3jFso4/8A31f3et61ECZajbpPIv7/dl0KVz6+j1CrrLB7LkN+5R
        pFa74P0cocNv/HeuDqYVdnbp4G/+OTEfg+gQV1XnN/j3roB6XhiXvd5d0HMv7Bry/ayhw2/4ikRTeJ6n
        nsd+du7it1LF9TiBNNTOZLk12x1MMjKZ6xZL8ahUGd86ei0ipa9bXKepRi+3fuigK+BLXrCHI3Q0XHHv
        UXX9hy/r1J9+i5iPw1Cn3CuHT6vUddrBNJcWy6aVXrFw3J8ntXyu4m3ZOkw0etVcQYVXDwz5Z5EYPz7h
        L3xFomEq3QM68ad/r85bPq+8j48kg2K4jUxya3c0eZKRq8dp98xKh/u3v7R/+Cv1fXh3AcKNr0jUXTVf
        0tlH/1WdN9+vnkefqd+tSyE33Fajvg76jeO/H93lA1lyL+wc9s8iDdjeFhgP1tBRN+VTvep54ln1PP6s
        vO4B1+OYM9zOZLm1/j37kb5msZSISeWxP0jG5RF6fv3u4f+QoMNnCDrGLffSXvU++Uv1PbWONfIGGu6U
        e/VEr4r7jvlyg6FYJqn0NYtUuFgYLyI+b6oS0908NdArlpW/2G13BB0+Q9AxJvnXDqj/B+vV//RGVY6c
        cT1OKFxs7/Dc2h2+DLoktaxePuagO10/f7Xzor+gunpQDDAcgo4RKe49qvz6Pcpt2KXcC7tUPXrW9Uih
        c7Gd0nJrd2jix97XxGlGLrNqqfTw2P7ZrMOg514c5nY1wKcIOi7p6H1fV37dTpWPnGGbVociyYsH3a/7
        uqevWSQl42NajnG6QxxBR8AQdFzSrId/X5JUHSyotOeoinuOqrjtkHK/3K7SriOOpwuPSGr4b1evZ1Cl
        nV1KX3FZEycamVg6qcy1i5QfZse14UQntyq1cEaDpro4r1JVbqN/d+EDhkLQMWKxlrQyKxYqs2Kh9O/O
        va98oke5Nds0+Pw2Df5im7zTfW6HNOxSW43m1u7wZdAlKbt6+aiDnlnp7nGpxa0HpXzJ2esDY+G/83MI
        lMT0DrXfcaNm/dU9WrTpK5r1+KfU8utXq8YVwHV3sVPukjS4xsf3o49hg5nsDUsbMMnIsH6OIOIIHXUT
        jcfUeusKtd66QuWTPer73jr1PPGsKl1cBV8PlzpCz7+4U16l6svH6qZXLJRScak48nV0p/efE3QEEEfo
        aIjEtA5N/sMPacHzD2naQx9TbHq765EC71JBrw0WVXjtQHOGGaVoKqHM9SM/hR7JppS6Ym4DJxqe53nK
        bRjbbXaASwQdDRVNJjTxzvdqwZq/1NTP/66iEye4Him4RnDknV/n59PuI98GNn3tImdnGko7j6jWl3fy
        2sB4EHQ0RSyT1KQ/+KAWrvsLtf3ee1yPE0iREQTO1+voq0a+js76OTB6BB1NFWvNauZf3KU5T35GsVmT
        XI8TKJH4pb9d8xt3yyuWmzDN6KWvmi8Ns33t27m8wj0/3PPPAZ8j6HCi5eZ3aMGzX1D7R3/N9SjBMZLn
        bxcrF99/3KFoMjGynd/i0bo8R32sOEJHUBF0OBObkNGML31c07/yCWkER59hN9K9w3O+Xke/9Gn31Lvm
        K5ZNNWGaCxX3HZN3pt/JawPjxU9RONfxkZs05x/+s6IdWdejmJDz8Tp6ZgRBZ/92YGwIOnyh5d1LddnT
        /02JBdNdjxJ4+Zf2qZoruB5jSOkr5ytyiaNv7j8HxoagwzdSC6Zr7lMPKH7ZFNejBFqk6im/wZ/7kEcT
        8Us+cCW9YkGTprkQR+gIMoIOX0lM69DcJ/+TolPbXI8SaLm1/j3tfrHb16JT25SY1tHEad5UOnxK1WPd
        Tl4bqAeCDt9JzpumuX//GUXaMq5HCSw/Bz1z3eJh/8zlw2U4OkfQEXT4UvqKuZr99U+qxjNexqSw5aAq
        vYOuxxhS6p3zVIsM/T829Q43271KrJ8j+Ag6fKtl9XJN+qMPux4jkCK1mm8DFcumlFw89HPO0++Y1+Rp
        3pRbz/7tCDaCDl+b8ie3KXWlux/yQebn0+6p5UMfibt6IEv5eLcqB046eW2gXgg6fC2aTGjm1/5gxFuG
        4k2BC3oq7uy2xTxH5zCAoMP3Uotmasp9t7keI3CKu46ofLrX9RhDSi2bfeH7lsx29oQ1LoiDBRd/wDLq
        Ztecu+vyeWoRKZJKKDoho8SMiUrMn6r0O+cps2qZ0lctcPYDsdE6PvF+9Xzz56ocPu16lMCISMq/sEuJ
        31rpepQLJJfMuvB9Q0S+WXI8kAUGEPSAidQkFcryCmUVT/epuPWgBn64SZIU7WhR2x2r1PHxW5RaOPRF
        R0EVSyc15dO36/i9X3c9SqDk1u5Qmw+Dnpg7RUrFpWLljfelLncT9MrZfpV2HxU3VCDoOOVuiNczqJ5H
        n1Hnez6rY59+VJWzth4y0Xr7uxWfN9X1GIEyuHa76xGGFI3FlHzbL51DnYZvhvz63cQcJhB0gyK1mvq+
        vUad7/msBn6+xfU4dRONxzTxP77f9RiBUuk8qdLRM67HGFJy8VtPuyeXznEyB6fbYQVBN8zrHlDXnV9R
        9+M/cz1K3bT9zmqueB+l/LqdrkcY0vn3okeyKSVnT3YyR/5FrnCHDQTduEhNOvm5b6r7iWddj1IX8fYW
        TfjA1a7HCJRBn96+llzwZtCTi2c6maHSl1Nh2yEnrw3UG0EPiRP/9Zu+XU8dLT9e5OVnuTX+/P+eXDRj
        yLebqbBpjyK1mpPXBuqNoIdEpFbTsXu/rupA3vUo45a9+QrVolzGNFLVY90qdp5wPcYFEvOmvfF2cpGb
        I3TuP4clBD1Eqse61f3Iv7geY9xiEzJKr1joeoxAya3z32n3eEeLIu1ZSRp2b/dGy7F+DkMIesicffSn
        qhZKrscYt8zVC1yPECi5Nf4LunTuUbmSlFzY/CP0aq6owqudTX9doFEIesjUenPKPRf8W9lSDp+bHUQ5
        n14/kZg75dzf50+7xEfWX+GlfYpUvaa/LtAoBD2EBp/f6nqEcUs6CECQeWcHVNjZ5XqMC8RnTVJ0apti
        2VTTX5v7z2ENQQ+hwtbg36YTnznJ9QiB48enryVmT1byMje7//n1efHAWBH0ECobeO5ztKPF9QiB48fT
        7vGp7W+52r1ZvGJZ+Zf2Nf11gUYi6CHkGbh1LcpucaOWe2GXvGrV9RhvEZvapoSD/fkLr3a+5cEwgAU8
        bS2Eah4baYRRrT+v4tZDylzlnzsEWlYvV8vq5U1/3dx6bleDPRyhh1B0Qtr1COPmDRZdjxBIflxHd4H1
        c1hE0EMoMSv4F5R5eYI+FgRd8ipV5TfucT0GUHcEPYSSS2Zd+oN8rsYR+pjk1u+SVyq7HsOp4taDquX4
        +oE9BD2Esjc2f82y3rzBgusRgqlQVuGVcO+Olmf9HEYR9JCpRSOacMtVrscYN2+AoI9V2E+780AWWEXQ
        Q2bCB65WYsZE12OMW/ngKdcjBFaYg+55nnIbOEKHTQQ9RGqRiKZ8+nbXY9RFqfO46xECK795r6ohXUMu
        7TyiWm/O9RhAQxD0EJl4z68rvXyu6zHqouTD53sHRrmqwua9rqdwIs/+7TCMoIdE+volmnr/b7seo24I
        +vgMhvS0Ow9kgWUEPQRS75yn2Y99StGkje1SvUpV5YPB34/epbCuo+deZP0cdhF041puvUpzn3pAcUMP
        MyluOcg+3ONUeLVT1f5wrSUX9x2Td7rP9RhAwxB0oyLZlKZ94aOa8/i9irUEf6vX8+XWhfPosp4iXi10
        +5nnOTqHcTycxZp0Qu0fuUmT77tNiantrqdpiLCeLq633Nodar11hesxmob1c1hH0A2oRaTMNYvU+lsr
        1fbbqxSf1Op6pIbxSmXuI66T3Br/PR+9kdhQBtYR9KCIRxVJJRTrmHDuGdJzpyi1ZJZSV85T5vrLTa2R
        X0x+016pEO69yOuluKNLlbP9pn8BfF3p8ClVj551PQbQUAS9SZZ2PeZ6BBP6vrvW9QhmRHTuqLXtQ9e5
        HqXh2L8dYcBFcQiM6kBefU9vcD2GKWE57c7pdoQBQUdg9D+9kdPtdRaWCwy5IA5hQNARGD1PPu96BHPK
        +46rfLzb9RgNVT7Ro0onGxHBPoKOQMht2K3iS/tcj2FSbt1O1yM0FPu3IywIOgLh1Be/63oEs3Jrba+j
        s36OsCDo8L3+n76swqZwPh2sGayvo3OFO8KCoMPXvGpVp7/0lOsxTKt0nVHp0CnXYzRE5Wy/iruOuB4D
        aAqCDl/r+cZzKvEDueGsHqXnN+xRxPUQQJMQdPhWYfcRnXrw267HCAWrQed2NYQJQYcvecWyjv3x/+Ex
        qU0yaPTCuDwXxCFECDp86fT/+L5K2w+7HiM0vFN9Ku456nqMuqr251TYesj1GEDTEHT4Tt8/rdfZ//1j
        12OEjrXT7vmNexWp1VyPATQNQYevDDy/Vcc+9Ygi/BxuOmun3Vk/R9gQdPhG/pX9OvKJv5EqnutRQim3
        bqc8z85/e9bPETYEHb5Q2NmlrjsflvIl16OEVq03p6KR6xaquaIKr3a6HgNoKoIO5wbXbNeh2x+U1z3g
        epTQyxtZRy+8vI8zPQgdgg6ner6zRod/78uqDRRcjwLZWUfPv8h2rwifuOsBEE6e5+nMl/9RZ//qaXby
        8pH8i7vllSuKJoL9o4EL4hBGwf6uRSCVDp/S8fse5aIlH6rliiq8dkDZaxe7HmXMvGJZ+c08zAfhwyl3
        NFXPPzyvA7d+npj7WNDvRy+8doAdBhFKBB1NUTpyRl13fVUnPvOYaoNF1+PgIoL+fPQ8p9sRUpxyR0NV
        ugd09n/+s7r/9hmpxFFTEOQ37lW1UFIsnXQ9ypjkOPuDkCLoaIhqvqSex57Rma/9ULW+vOtxMBqligov
        7VPL6uWuJxk1r1JVfuMe12MAThB01FX5RI96v/UL9fzdc6qe7HU9DsYot2Z7IINe3HaIJR2EFkFHXeTW
        71L348+q/0ebFKmyoUfQBfXCONbPEWYEHWNW2HFYA//ysvqf3qDSriOSxD3lRuRf6VR1IK/YhIzrUUaF
        9XOEGUHHiHnVqgov71f/j1/SwE82q3LwlOuR0CCRqqf8hj2a8L53uR5lxDzPU34DO8QhvAg6hlXtz6nw
        SqfyG/cov2mv8pv3sj4ZIoNrdwQq6KVdR+T15FyPAThD0KFqoaTygZMq7T+u0r7jKu0/ruLWgyruPKJI
        jQeTh1XQHtSSX8/ROcKNoBvhVaqqlSq/+qt83tsVeQN5Vc/0q3q6X5Uzfaqe6Tv39ulelQ+eUvnIGUWG
        6Dbr4eFW2HZQle4BxSdOcD3KiLB/O8IusnP2XRyCAQAQcGz9CgCAAQQdAAADCDoAAAYQdAAADCDoAAAY
        QNABADCAoAMAYABBBwDAAIIOAIABBB0AAAMIOgAABhB0AAAMIOgAABhA0AEAMICgAwBgAEEHAMAAgg4A
        gAEEHQAAAwg6AAAGEHQAAAwg6AAAGEDQAQAwgKADAGAAQQcAwACCDgCAAQQdAAADCDoAAAYQdAAADCDo
        AAAYQNABADCAoAMAYABBBwDAAIIOAIABBB0AAAMIOgAABhB0AAAMIOgAABhA0AEAMICgAwBgAEEHAMAA
        gg4AgAEEHQAAAwg6AAAGEHQAAAwg6AAAGEDQAQAwgKADAGAAQQcAwACCDgCAAQQdAAADCDoAAAYQdAAA
        DCDoAAAYQNABADCAoAMAYABBBwDAAIIOAIABBB0AAAMIOgAABhB0AAAMIOgAABhA0AEAMICgAwBgAEEH
        AMAAgg4AgAEEHQAAAwg6AAAGEHQAAAwg6AAAGEDQAQAwgKADAGAAQQcAwACCDgCAAQQdAAADCDoAAAYQ
        dAAADCDoAAAYQNABADCAoAMAYABBBwDAAIIOAIABBB0AAAMdckDOAAABpUlEQVQIOgAABhB0AAAMIOgA
        ABhA0AEAMICgAwBgAEEHAMAAgg4AgAEEHQAAAwg6AAAGEHQAAAwg6AAAGEDQAQAwgKADAGAAQQcAwACC
        DgCAAQQdAAADCDoAAAYQdAAADCDoAAAYQNABADCAoAMAYABBBwDAAIIOAIABBB0AAAMIOgAABhB0AAAM
        IOgAABhA0AEAMICgAwBgAEEHAMAAgg4AgAEEHQAAAwg6AAAGEHQAAAwg6AAAGEDQAQAwgKADAGAAQQcA
        wACCDgCAAQQdAAADCDoAAAYQdAAADCDoAAAYQNABADCAoAMAYABBBwDAAIIOAIABBB0AAAMIOgAABhB0
        AAAMIOgAABhA0AEAMICgAwBgAEEHAMAAgg4AgAEEHQAAAwg6AAAGEHQAAAwg6AAAGEDQAQAwgKADAGAA
        QQcAwACCDgCAAQQdAAADCDoAAAYQdAAADCDoAAAYQNABADCAoAMAYABBBwDAAIIOAIABBB0AAAMIOgAA
        BhB0AAAMIOgAABhA0AEAMICgAwBgAEEHAMAAgg4AgAEEHQAAAwg6AAAG/H/Gcfz/ut42LAAAAABJRU5E
        rkJggg==
</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

I'm expecting this to build fine - it builds fine on my local machine.

It throws this error: `/home/travis/build/inventor02/BMICalculator/BMICalculator/MainForm.resx(270,5): error MSB3103: Invalid Resx file. No valid icon entry were found. Line 270, position 5. [/home/travis/build/inventor02/BMICalculator/BMICalculator/BMICalculator.vbproj]`

Comment: try to find out what's in Line 270, position 5??

Comment: @zackraiyan it's just the closing `</data>` tag

Comment: umm...dunnno if it'll work or not but create a duplicate project...i mean create a new project and copy/paste all .vb and .resx files to ur new project... see if the problem exists

Comment: Consider removing and adding a different icon. When I added your Icon, I got a antivirus message of potential virus. If that solves, its icon issue